# Compare two List<String> values in android

Tags: android, string, list, equals

Dear all i am comparing two List in android if both values are same and it is returning true that is fine but i want to know how many values have been correct between the list string if it is not matching how to achieve this Help is appreciated. Below is my code.

```
            List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(i1.values());
            ///list 1 = [-ful; to be full of; play; playful; full of play]
    List<String> acct_Rte_Cdes_A = Arrays.asList(result) ;
            ///acct_Rte_Cdes_A  = [-ful; to be full of; play; playful; full of play]
             if (list1.equals(acct_Rte_Cdes_A)) { 
                // do what you want to do if the string is there
                //System.out.println("True");
     }  else {
        System.out.println("False");
         }
```

Comment: If they are not equal, loop through them comparing items 1by1 yourself and keep a simple integer as count which you increment everytime the items match.

Comment: Got struggle in same issue, did you got the answer? if so please post the correct answer. i need to get the common values from the two list. i have followed some post but thats not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int correctCount=0, incorrectCount = 0;
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(i1.values());

List<String> acct_Rte_Cdes_A = Arrays.asList(result)    

for(String tmp1: list1) {
    for(String tmp2: list2) {
        if(tmp1.compareTo(tmp2) == 0) {
            correctCount++;
        } else {
            incorrectCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

it's time complexity is high but it will do the trick.

Comment: this is checking all the string in my list and returning i want how many are correct how many are wrong inside my list not as a whole

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Collection#retainAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29). like

```
List<Integer> common = new ArrayList<Integer>(listA);
common.retainAll(listB);
// common now contains only the elements which are contained in listA and listB.
```

So you can check for size if it is greater than 0 it meanse some elements are common. And which are common elements `common` will tell.

Answer (score 3):

You can use containsAll method on Java collection. Here is an example.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] a) {
    String elements[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(elements));

    elements = new String[] { "A", "B", "C" };
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(elements));

    System.out.println(list.containsAll(list2)); // true
    System.out.println(list2.containsAll(list)); // false
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you can use **apache CollectionUtils library to improve performances**. Depending on the type of Collection provided, this method will be much faster than calling Collection.containsAll(Collection) instead.
See the doc of apache containsAll [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29).

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the lists yourself checking for equality and at the same time keeping a counter to indicate on which position they differ.

Sample (pseudo) code:

```
//if equal return 0, else position of difference
//keep in mind that item at index [0] is first, so return would be 1 if lists differ there
public int checkEquality(List list1, List list2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); ++i) {
        if (list1[i] != list2[i])
             return i + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also keep in mind, that you'd have to check if the lists are of the same size, and decide what to do if they are not (for example, return -1 to indicated this).

Answer (score 0):

```
list1.containsAll(acct_Rte_Cdes_A)

boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c)
```

> Returns true if this list contains all of the elements of the
>   specified collection.